# Combine like rows in table that used count function in the select

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a query to access health information from my student information system for state and county record compliance. We are using SQL Server 2000 (legacy system) as the backend. The query is this:

```
select
i.Description Immunization, 
             Case
                When si.Exempt = 'P' Then Count (LName)
                Else 0
                END AS 'Personal Exempt',
             Case
                When si.Exempt = 'M' Then Count (LName)
                Else '0'
                END AS 'Medical Exempt',
             Case
                When si.Exempt = 'R' Then Count (LName)
                Else 0
                END AS 'Religious Exempt',
             Case
                When si.Exempt = 'I' Then Count (LName)--AS 'Personal Exemption'
                Else '0'
                END AS 'Had Illness'                    
from student cross join immunization i left join StImmunization si on si.sno = Student.sno and si.immcode = i.code 
where Student.Status = 'A'  and  i.TotalReq > 0 
Group BY i.Description, si.exempt
```

The output is this:

```
Immunization          PersonalExempt   MedicalExempt   RelgiousExempt  HadIllness

Chicken pox (Varicella)   0               0                 0              6
Chicken pox (Varicella)   1               0                 0              0
Hepatitis B               1               0                 0              0
T_DAP                     0               0                 0              0
Polio                     0               0                 0              0
Diptheria, Tetanus,
Pertussis                 0               0                 0              0
Hepatitis B               0               0                 0              0
Diptheria, Tetanus,
Pertussis                 0               0                 0              0
MMR                       0               0                 0              0
T_DAP                     1               0                 0              0
MMR                       1               0                 0              0
Polio                     1               0                 0              0
Chicken pox (Varicella)   1               0                 0              0
```

I would like the output to combine the like rows of the columns so it looks like this and if necessary add like row and columns:

```
Imunization            PersonalExempt  Medical Exempt  Religious Exempt Had Illness
Chicken pox (Varicella)   2               0                  0            6
Hepatitis B               1               0                  0            0
T_DAP                     1               0                  0            0
Polio                     1               0                  0            0
Diptheria, Tetanus,
Pertussis                 1               0                  0            0
```

Notice row one (below) is the sum of rows 2 and 13 (above). Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Remove si.exempt from the group by clause

Answer (score 0):

Better to use SUM here -- then you can select a 1 or 0 to make the sum give the count.

Old SQL `GROUP BY` trick.

```
select 
  i.Description AS Immunization, 
  SUM(Case When si.Exempt = 'P' Then 1 Else 0 END) AS 'Personal Exempt',
  SUM(Case When si.Exempt = 'M' Then 1 Else 0 END) AS 'Medical Exempt',
  SUM(Case When si.Exempt = 'R' Then 1 Else 0 END) AS 'Religious Exempt',
  SUM(Case When si.Exempt = 'I' Then 1 Else 0 END) AS 'Had Illness'                    
from student cross join immunization i left join StImmunization si on si.sno = Student.sno and si.immcode = i.code 
where Student.Status = 'A'  and  i.TotalReq > 0 
Group BY i.Description
```